# C macro trick for selective replace

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

Is there a macro trick to rename just the function calls without affecting the function definition, specifically for gcc/cpp:

```
#define get_resolution __mock_get_resolution
```

The above macro changes all places, but I just want this to take effect for the function call `get_resolution();` without affecting the definition `void get_resolution()`

```
void get_resolution()
{
}

void display()
{
    get_resolution();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the C preprocessor has no semantic knowledge of the structure of the C program, it just sees text tokens.

One option would be to `#undef` the macro before the definition and redefine it afterwards, but this is messy.  Another option would be to add a macro to the definition of each function you want to mock like this:

```
#if DO_MOCKING
#define IMPLEMENT_MOCKABLE_FUNCTION(funcname) _real_ ## funcname
#define get_resolution _mock_get_resolution
#else
#define IMPLEMENT_MOCKABLE_FUNCTION(funcname) funcname
#endif

...

void IMPLEMENT_MOCKABLE_FUNCTION(get_resolution)()
{
    ...
}
```

Also note that identifiers beginning with two underscores, as well as identifiers beginning with an underscore followed by a capital letter, are reserved by the implementation (i.e. the compiler and standard libraries).  So I've renamed the identifiers in the example above to use a single underscore and a lowercase letter.

Answer (score 3):

As gcc-specific solution,

```
 The `alias' attribute causes the declaration to be emitted as an
 alias for another symbol, which must be specified.  For instance,

      void __f () { /* Do something. */; }
      void f () __attribute__ ((weak, alias ("__f")));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
#define get_resolution __mock_get_resolution
```

somewhere globally accessible (like a header you always include etc.) and then do this:

```
#undef get_resolution
void get_resolution()
{
}
#define get_resolution __mock_get_resolution

void display()
{
    get_resolution();
}
```

Ugly hack, but it will save you having to write a sed(1) script.

Test case follows:

```
$ gcc -o test test.c
$ ./test
__mock_up
$ cat test.c        
#include <stdio.h>

#define get_resolution __mock_up

int
__mock_up()
{
        printf("__mock_up\n");  
}

#undef get_resolution
int 
get_resolution()
{

}
#define get_resolution __mock_up

int main()
{
       get_resolution();
       return 0;
}
$
```